# Identify this uniformed figure with four yellow buttons and a grey belt

Tags: minifigure-identification

My son recently got a huge box of figures and pieces (from what I can tell an original spaceship with figure too) and I can't figure out what set is from or how old this figure is.

[image: mystery figure]

[image]

He has four yellow buttons and a silver/greyish belt on a black sticker on his chest. Body and legs are black and no other discerning features about him.

Answer (score 11):

Looks like a 1980's Fireman.  Found an example from the 620 lego set:

[image]

Comment: i think it is this one, i found a small hatchet and what looks like that lattice part of the car too! thank you

Answer (score 5):

1978 Fireman. I've got a couple from set 374 and 602.

[image]

[image]